# Geomesa: saving KML in Accumulo

Tags: geomesa

How can I save KML data in Geomesa? My main interest is programmatically and not with a Geomesa cmd line tool. Of'course a spatial index should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The export could be handled by getting a GeoMesa FeatureCollection representing the desired features and using the XSD-KML GeoTools module [1] to encode the collection as KML.

Disclaimer:  I haven't used this plugin myself, but looks like it'd do exactly what you want!

1. http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html#

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was mainly interested programmatically inserting (and querying) KML data to GeoMesa. I have found 2 ways: 
1) http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/native_api.html: [GeoMesa Native API] GeoMesaIndex<DomainObject>#insert(...) #query(...)
2) http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-accumulo.html: [GeoTools DataStore API] DataStore.insertFeatures|queryFeatures

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to use the GeoTools KML modules to get a 'DataStore' from the KML and write the directory to a GeoMesa DataStore.